# Bourbon font-face outputting src surrounded by quotes

Tags: sass, font-face, bourbon

So i have just recently upgraded to the latest bourbon (4.0.2 and sass (3.4.8). Since doing this, the `font-face` mixin outputs the src surrounded by double quotes, which is invalid and is breaking by fonts.

`@include font-face('Avenir', '../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular');`

Expected result (no double quotes around src):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: none;
  src: url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
  src: url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.ttf') format('ttf'), url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.svg#avenir') format('svg');
}
```

Output (double quotes around src):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: none;
  src: "url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype')";
  src: "url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')", "url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.woff') format('woff')", "url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.ttf') format('ttf')", "url('../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular.svg#avenir') format('svg')";

}
```

The `font-face` mixin is as follows (see annotated line):

```
@mixin font-face(
  $font-family,
  $file-path,
  $weight: normal,
  $style: normal,
  $asset-pipeline: $asset-pipeline,
  $file-formats: eot woff ttf svg) {

  $font-url-prefix: font-url-prefixer($asset-pipeline);

  @font-face {
    font-family: $font-family;
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;

    @if contains($file-formats, eot) {
      // THIS IS THE TROUBLE LINE
      src: "#{$font-url-prefix}('#{$file-path}.eot') format('embedded-opentype')";
    }

    src: font-source-declaration(
      $font-family,
      $file-path,
      $asset-pipeline,
      $file-formats,
      $font-url-prefix
    );
  }
}
```

Is anyone else able to replicate this?

Any ideas are really appreciated.

Comment: I tried to put your code in sassmeister and it works. http://sassmeister.com/gist/3c7bde1d4fde0ae92feb .

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like this could be a sass version issue then?

Comment: Yes, Sassmeister uses sass 3.4.7, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: OK, i looked at the 3.4.8 release and there is nothing in there that would have caused this... https://github.com/sass/sass/releases/tag/3.4.8